# Calculating number of operations in function using wrappers

Tags: python, sorting, evaluation

I am trying to create a toolkit for analyzing implemented sorting algorithms. I write this toolkit as a python module.

For example, I've already created functions to calculate memory usage and execution time:

```html
import tracemalloc
import time

import numpy as np

def cal_memory(func):
    """
    Function to calculate used memory

    """

    def m_usage_tracked(*args):

        tracemalloc.start() 
    
        func(*args)

        m_res = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
        tracemalloc.stop()
        tracemalloc.clear_traces()
        
        print("Memory: {}KB with peak {}KB".format(m_res[0]/10**3, m_res[1]/10**3 ) )

    return m_usage_tracked


def cal_time(func):
    """
    Function to calculate an estimated time
    
    """

    def t_usage_tracked(*args):

        start = time.clock_gettime(time.CLOCK_MONOTONIC)

        func(*args)

        t_res = time.clock_gettime(time.CLOCK_MONOTONIC) - start

        print("Time: {} seconds".format(t_res) )

    return t_usage_tracked
```

How can I write a similar function to calculate a number of operations in function?